# Set flag for Print Spooler API in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, printing, unmanaged

In this [MSDN API Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162723(v=vs.85).aspx), it says:

> A bit flag. If you set the PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH flag in a
>   call to the FindNextPrinterChangeNotification function, the function
>   provides current data for all monitored printer information fields.
>   The FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification function ignores the Flags
>   member.

However, I cannot find anywhere of the API that tell the value of the flag `PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH`. This is my structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS
{
    public int dwVersion = 2;
    public int dwFlags;
    public int Count = 2;
    public IntPtr lpTypes;

    public PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS()
    {
        int bytesNeeded = (2 + PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE.JOB_FIELDS_COUNT + PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE.PRINTER_FIELDS_COUNT) * 2;
        PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE pJobTypes = new PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_TYPE();
        lpTypes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytesNeeded);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(pJobTypes, lpTypes, true);
    }
}
```

How can I set the dwFlags value according to the API documentation? Also there are many other flags in the document that do not come with value too. Where are they stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the documentation you are referred to:

*Header: Winspool.h*

Your copy of this file is likely located in *C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um*

Open it in a text editor and search for the constant, you will see its value is 1.

```
#define PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH  0x01
```

If you dont have the header files, you can install the Windows SDK or just google for *"define PRINTER_NOTIFY_OPTIONS_REFRESH"*

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the Google tip. I did try the flag name on Google but did not find anything.

Comment: Can I ask one more question? In the reference, it says the DLL file is "Spoolss.dll". However, if I use `[DllImport("winspool.drv"...`, it works, but `[DllImport("Spoolss.dll"...`, it does not?

Comment: That's where the function is implemented, you call it via Winspool.drv which is the client interface to the spooler system

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!